# How to convert an ArrayList of byte[] to an array of Integer in Android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, integer, arrays

I'm trying to convert an `ArrayList<byte[]> listByte` to an `Integer[] arrInteger`. I'm getting the `listByte`of pictues from a server through an object. My goal is to get this `Array of Integer`(pictures) to later use it in a `ListView`(`arrayAdapter = new MyClass(MyActivity.this, stringArr, arrInteger);`.
I tried like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
     integerList.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(objectList.get(i).getPicture()).getInt(i));
    /*integerList.add(new BigInteger(objectList.get(i).getImage()).intValue());*/ //I tried this too
    }
```

and to an `Array of Integer`, like this:

```
Integer[] arrInteger = new Integer[integerList.size()];
arrInteger = integerList.toArray(arrInteger);
```

When i run the app, the `ListView`is showing without pictures. So I used debug and I found that my `arrInteger = null`!. How do I convert correctly?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, an image can't be represented as an Integer

Comment: @carl is byte[] the representation of a single integer

Comment: @Egor: The images stored in the `drawable folder`, youc an get them like this: `Integer[] images = {R.drawable.icon,,,,};`. I wanna do like this, to get an `Array of Integer`?

Comment: @Eduardo Pérez: where/how to do that?

Comment: @DAO: I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: @carl since Integer is represented by 4 bytes, I was asking if integerList  is an ArrayList of Integers where byte[] is the integer with length=4

Comment: @DAO I uploaded pictures as `byte[] picture`to a server after converting them from `Bitmap`. Now when i get them as `ArrayList<byte[]>` I wanna  show them in a `ListView`. I can't use them as `byte[]`,so it'll be as `Integer[]` or back to `Bitmap`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode back to Bitmap

```
   ArrayList<Bitmap> imgs = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
   for(byte[] array: listByte)
   {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length); //use android built-in functions
        imgs.add(bm);
   }
```

Comment: The problem that to use the pictures in a `ListView`, I used this `constructor`: `arrayAdapter = new MyClass(MyActivity.this, stringArr, arrInteger);`, `Integer[] arrInteger`. Can I use `imgs` as `Bitmap[] arr` after converting from an `ArrayList`to an `Array`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works very well now. Instead for `setImageResource()` i used `setImageBitmap()`.